# Linear Layout Horizontal, Gravity Problems

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-linearlayout

I've placed three buttons as below,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Standard"
            android:id="@+id/standard_map"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="satellite"
            android:id="@+id/satellite"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hybrid"
            android:id="@+id/hybrid"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="13.0827"
        map:cameraTargetLng="80.2707"
        map:cameraBearing="112.5"
        map:cameraTilt="65"
        map:cameraZoom="20"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The output yield is as below:
[image explaining the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kryL9.png)

The orientation of the inner Linear Layout is horizontal and that's perfectly fine. I need the buttons to be aligned in centre (Vertically centred). Even when I use `android:gravity="centre"`, it aligns the buttons horizontally centred which is of no use. **I need the buttons to be vertically centred in an Horizontal Linear Layout.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your Question, you want to make middle button
in center, so I have done some changes, please update your code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/standard_map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Standard" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/satellite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="satellite"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hybrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hybrid"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraBearing="112.5"
        map:cameraTargetLat="13.0827"
        map:cameraTargetLng="80.2707"
        map:cameraTilt="65"
        map:cameraZoom="20" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know if any problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the second LinearLayout change layout_gravity and orientation properties. So, your second layout should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

And you will achieve this:

[image]